# TypeScript pick call signature from function interface

Tags: typescript

There is a function interface with statics:

```
interface MyFunction {
  (value: string): string;
  a: string;
  b: string;
}
```

How do I `Pick` the call signature only (ignore `a` and `b`)?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot Pick a call signature as it is not a property of your interface.
You can do next:

```
interface MyFunction {
    (value: string): string;
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

type Callable<T> = T extends (...args: any[]) => any ? (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T> : never;

type MyFunctionCallSignature = Callable<MyFunction>;
```

Comment: I didn't know the type `Parameters` existed. When did it get introduced ?

Comment: Parameters was released in 3.1 according to this https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype

Answer (score 1):

You can't `Pick` it because you can't pass a `string` key that will select it, however here are constructed types that will infer the correct type of your Function :

```js
interface MyFunction {
  (value: string): string;
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

type SignatureType<T> = T extends (...args: infer R) => any ? R : never;
type CallableType<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> = (...args: SignatureType<T>) => ReturnType<T>;

type CallableOfMyFunction = CallableType<MyFunction>; // Type (value: string) => string
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8BiBXECzAD2IyA3gFDLIAUAbnADbYQBcyAzmFKAOYCUbTtxA8A3JWRxBXXuKoAjacLHkAvuXJh0ABxQBlYDxBww2KBAAqOiAB4LAPmQBeZBeQQAHpBAATdjQA6ILgoHnY2UBhoZAAlPmdHOBB0ZAB+WOQ2EAhaaHEtXWQAYUYGOHkGS2s7dy8IX39qIICQsLYk9ABtAF14p0Tkxxcm4NDw5AMjEzMq3Tt7PscYiFMoECs5h3FNa2LS8sqAeRgMHDwCYmc9hjKK2dtT3HwiEHtRZAB6D9ddukZmJS8RYcGQiIA)