# Typescript, extract multiple call signatures from interface

Tags: typescript

Given the following:

```
interface Foo {
  attr: string;
  (a: string): number;
  (a: number): number;
}
```

How one would create a type that only select the function overloads, meaning:

```
interface Bar {
  (a: string): number;
  (a: number): number;
}
```

I found solution when there is [just one call signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58657325/typescript-pick-call-signature-from-function-interface), my situation is when there are more than one call signatures.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameters generic of overloaded function doesn't contain all options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59538756/2887218), it's not completely impossible but it's ugly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no perfect way to do this. There is no support to just remove the properties and the version that extracts function signatures has limitations. We can get  get a version with multiple overloads to work:

```
interface Foo {
  attr: string;
  (a: string): number;
  (a: number): number;
}

type JustSignatures<T> =
  T extends { (...args: infer A1): infer R1; (...args: infer A2): infer R2; (...args: infer A3): infer R3; (...args: infer A4): infer R4 } ?
  {
    (...args: A1): R1; (...args: A2): R2; (...args: A3): R3; (...args: A4): R4
  } :
  T extends { (...args: infer A1): infer R1; (...args: infer A2): infer R2; (...args: infer A3): infer R3 } ?
  {
    (...args: A1): R1; (...args: A2): R2; (...args: A3): R3
  } :
  T extends { (...args: infer A1): infer R1; (...args: infer A2): infer R2 } ?
  {
    (...args: A1): R1; (...args: A2): R2
  } :
  T extends { (...args: infer A1): infer R1; } ?
  {
    (...args: A1): R1;
  } :
  never;


type FooSignatures = JustSignatures<Foo>
// type FooSignatures = {
//     (a: string): number;
//     (a: number): number;
// }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=32&ssc=5&pln=29&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyycYYUAXMgM5mgDmA3AUQBRyU1T0CUlIArgFsARtCaFkbPkNFReyASLEEAvgQJgAngAcUAKX40AysDogS-KBCoAeACoA+ZAF5myO8ggAPSCAAmVDiSAHShcFB0VJSgMNDIAIIAjPIxcQBKiQwhYRFRyKlQCQBMKSCxhWlFWSyhweGR0WVx8QDMpeXIaS3VtfV5BQkALO3pg8gqyAD8bngSrL25lEnyGT05DcUrVdl1iwltlF1ruxvxw4eDbhPkbh7evgFBNev9TYXLjR2rO32fzSV-CrbZ4nV4dVojCotcZTGZueYvJbJQ6ZH57eIAzrAhanA6dFpXZA3CR3HwQfyBbBojYDD75N6dVEg3708GYgaVGHTCSzIgI0FIlZMnF5DFbQnEoikh6U6lg5rI1npVETblEXl85noxWrCVuEAQABuynw6nwWl0aEwJjMFisgWcyAMxlM5jAlmsNgw6AcZoA9H7kBaUN6bW6PQ6cAQA3zWOxqLQQHR5IpZOIY7GpAoZNAUzmoOnAyogA)

This will still have the limitation of not working for functions with generic type parameters. Also I seem to remember a bug in the compiler that cause the above approach to have issues in some corner cases, but it should for the most part work.

Comment: It does work though I can even begin to understand what's going on here. Thanks!