# How to remove a key/property from a function type

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

How do I remove `name` from the following function type:

```
type Func = {
  (): number
  name: string
}
```

`Omit<Func, 'name'>` result in `never`.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMZQLxQN4CgpQBQCUAXFAnALYBGEATgNw6kCG5EJAzsDQJYIDmDAL4NQkKAA00UAPLluwADzxkAGigByBCwjqAfAwAmEJABsmNaCYjAoADxLiGtwnSA)

Comment: Now that's interesting, it loses the call signature. It retains other properties (if there are any), but loses the call signature. (FWIW, I don't think this is a [tag:conditional-types] question, but I'm not sure enough to remove the tag. :-) )

Comment: (Side note: JavaScript functions always have a `name` property (regardless of whether you tell TypeScript that) unless you play games to get rid of it, but that isn't what the problem is.)

Comment: `keyof` in `Omit` won't catch the call signature. Easiest solution is probably to create two distinct types - one for function and one for the object, which are then intersected. Or you extract the signature - have a look at:

Comment: [Extract call signature from a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55376089/extract-call-signature-from-a-type) or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58657325/typescript-pick-call-signature-from-function-interface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do this because [`name` is part of the special built-in `Function` interface](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/8cd4793a9c93f2a50cc6b9b331b9f9bec74e8c98/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L93-L98), which all callables in TypeScript inherit from.  As soon as the compiler sees that a type is callable, it will have a `name` (and a `bind` and a `call` and an `apply`, etc).  You won't be able to widen the type to remove those keys.

See [microsoft/TypeScript#27575](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27575) for the canonical issue about this.  I don't know that anything will happen there, but that's where you should go to describe your use case and give a  if you want to increase the chance of it being addressed.

Anyway, the closest you will be able to get here is to have `name` be of type `never`, which is a narrowing and not a widening:

```
type MyFunc = {
  (): number;
  readonly name: never;
};
```

You can still call it:

```
declare const f: MyFunc;
const num = f(); // okay
```

And while it does *have* a `name`:

```
f.name; // no error here, but
```

That `name` is no longer seen as a usable `string` type:

```
f.name.toUpperCase(); // error
// Property 'toUpperCase' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

---

If, you were talking about a different property that's *not* built-in to `Function`, like

```
type MyFuncTwo = {
  (): number;
  title: string;
  age: number;
}
```

then you can remove those but not with `Omit<>`, which is a mapped type.  Mapped types skip call/construct signatures.  There's an open issue for that too: [microsoft/TypeScript#29261](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29261).  To work around that, you'd need to make your own type mapper that re-adds the call signature:

```
type MyOmit<T, K extends PropertyKey> =
  (T extends (...args: infer A) => infer R ? (...args: A) => R : unknown) & Omit<T, K>;
```

That works for the example above:

```
type MyFuncThree = MyOmit<MyFuncTwo, "title">;
// type MyFuncThree = (() => number) & Pick<MyFuncTwo, "age">
```

but there are all sorts of edge cases around overloads and maybe generics.  If you really want to see a non-workaround you might want to go to #29261 and give it a  and describe your use case.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgYygXigbwFBSgAoBKALimUQFsAjCAJwG58p6IBDAEwHtkAbEBXZUI5ZBABuDZgF9muThFR92bKKl4BnYFABm5OEjTMNybRWqY9JRlAD0dqNwDW7ELly6AdMmERbDhTcUAz03PRQABYMEAA0UDSIwB7eviJewNwAqmCQ9ADC7JoQNvaOoeG4gQAKYXmgUADkmTl5hcWNUDwQmkE6EAAeAJbmvFCgkE3iUvSNXh4T0IYoqAAqAO7BWHgEJGLUdEwswEPAfKJQ2vRDyADmzATstxeUtNK4MgvgSyAA8lSnAA8q3iAGkQgNgBBkJxerVuPUQKCICAAHyYFiEVYQqEw3qELyE1S3TTkG66BhQACCxEw6PJlIASlAAPxEQleYmk6m0jDo5nkFDOZDcdbIWkAMig-yBIKgoNR8kWsAQK1WkTY0CwcBlwEByzQG248QARCczhATYqqo5lQa1hqIFqiCQ6RY3vRJVBqkNUM59arDZtTU9LaigA)